# How can I get all pushed routes from the navigation stack in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

Is there is a way to get names of the pushed routes from the navigation stack ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe NavigatorObserver can help to achieve what you want

```
MaterialApp(
       navigatorObservers: [MyNavigatorObserver()],...)


class MyNavigatorObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  List<Route<dynamic>> routeStack = List();

  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    routeStack.add(route);
  }

  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic> previousRoute) {
    routeStack.removeLast();
  }

  @override
  void didRemove(Route route, Route previousRoute) {
    routeStack.removeLast();
  }

  @override
  void didReplace({Route newRoute, Route oldRoute}) {
    routeStack.removeLast();
    routeStack.add(newRoute);
  }
}
```